# How to multiplex camera/video stream?

Tags: streaming-video, uv4l

I'm streaming Raspberry's Pi h264-encoded `uv4l` video device with `netcat` like this:

```
cat /dev/video0 | nc -klp 2222
```

On the "client-side" I can view the stream with:

```
mplayer -fps 30 -demuxer h264es ffmpeg://tcp://rpi.local:2222
```

How can I turn this "client-side" into some kind of streaming server for multiple clients? The stream is "fine as it is", no need to re-encode it, just pass it thru to multiple clients.

*With all the flexibility of `uv4l` could I maybe fake somehow a local `/dev/video` from my network stream?*

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just use the native *UV4L Streaming Server*. According to [this tutorial](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/streaming-server/), you can open many raw `H264` streams at the same time over `HTTP` or `HTTPS`. The tutorial shows the following command using `vlc` client, but you can adapt it to `mplayer`.

```
cvlc http://raspberrypi:8080/stream/video.h264 --demux h264
```

In the tutorial, it's written that you can open one client "at a time", but this is no longer a limitation, provided that you also make sure that `inline-headers = yes` is specified in the configuration file. The advantage in using the Streaming Server is that it's the same OS process as the underlying UV4L driver and that you can control the max number of HTTP clients.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but my goal is to keep just **one** Raspberry Pi connection (to put the heavy client-handling on second machine).

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use [ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/), that comes with `nmap` package:

```
ncat rpi.local 2222 | ncat -kl 4444
```

This will listen to multiple client connections on port `4444`.
This method is as lightweight as the methods from question.